# Trying to calculate sum of weight

Tags: sql, oracle

i am returning four column with multiple rows values
and want aggregate of one of the column value in it.

i am returning four column with multiple rows values 
column: weight,a,b,c,d it contain eighteen rows of values now i want aggregate of one of column weight from it.i.e sum(weight)

```
select  a.prod_weight weight,a,b,c,d from tbl1
union
select  a.prod_weight weight,a,b,c,d from tbl2
```

Expected:sum of all values in weight column.
Actual:Only getting weight values in column how to aggregate it from the result of two table union no idea.

Comment: I'd guess you want UNION ALL instead of UNION here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select sum(weight) as totalweight
from
(
select  a.prod_weight as weight,a,b,c,d from tbl1
union all
select  a.prod_weight,a,b,c,d from tbl2
)A
```

Comment: query is fine but i want only single column totalweight and which give sum of every row value in weight  column as single totalweight

Comment: Do not use `union` unless you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  This will return incorrect results if the two tables have the same values.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
Select sum(isnull(weight,0)) as Weight, a, b, c, d from (
select  a.prod_weight weight, a, b, c, d from tbl1
union all
select  a.prod_weight weight, a, b, c, d from tbl2
) as d 
group by a, b, c, d
```

Or if you want to add sum in the last only then, in that case you don't need columns:-

```
select  a.prod_weight weight,a,b,c,d from tbl1
union all
select  a.prod_weight weight,a,b,c,d from tbl2
union all
Select sum(isnull(weight,0)) as Weight, null, null, null, null from (
select  a.prod_weight weight,a,b,c,d from tbl1
union all
select  a.prod_weight weight,a,b,c,d from tbl2
) as d
```